# Clang C to LLVM compilation prunes "mistaken code"

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm-clang

I am trying to understand the clang compiler for C, and the intermediate code it produces.

I have a series of functions that compile, producing LLVM-IR and I don't understand why.

Here is the first:

```
int f(int x){
}
```

This produces the LLVM code

```
define i32 @f(i32 %x) nounwind uwtable readnone{
  ret i32 undef
}
```

That is perfectly understandable I think.  The function body is undefined!

Here is the next C function:

```
int f(int x){
  if (x < 0) 
    {}
  else
    {}
}
```

When clang compiles this, it generates the exact same LLVM-IR.  The compiler recognizes that the body is garbage, and returns undefined!!!  The way LLVM knows this is garbage is its optimizer.  Clang --> LLVM uses a "return value collector" convention -- when defining a function -- %1 is allocated as the "return value."  All return statements update this value, and ultimately, there is one ret statement in LLVM at the end of the function body that essentially returns this value.  LLVM sees that a variable is allocated and returned without being updated or initialized, and sets it to undefined.

Now for the kicker!!

```
int f(int x){
  if (x<0)
    {}
  else
    {           
      return 3;
    }
}
```

Is converted to the following LLVM-IR.

```
define i32 @f(i32 %x) nounwind uwtable readnone {
  ret i32 3
}
```

For some reason, the undefined code is pruned off.  The C function should be undefined when (x<0)!!  Can anyone explain why this code is pruned off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`3` is a perfectly reasonable return value for a function with undefined behaviour.  Literally *any* return value would be allowed.

Comment: The function does not have UB. UB is only invoked if the caller uses the return value.

Comment: ... which is the only reason you might care about the `3` being returned, too.

Comment: If the caller only passes non-negative arguments then it can use the return value.

Comment: Fair enough.  You have plenty of rep to correct the wording if you have a better way to write the answer.

Comment: @R.. - You're saying that the function doesn't have undefined behavior unless the return value is read? When did C become Schrodinger's cat?

Comment: @DaoWen The execution of the function never invokes undefined behavior, reading its return value may.

Comment: I feel that the function is partial!  If f is called f(a)  with a >= 0, it certainly should exhibit well-defined behaviour.  However, if f(a) is called with a < 0, why is 3 acceptable?  Nothing should be returned.

Comment: @ouah - Why would reading an `int` "invoke undefined behavior"? Technically, I guess both you and R. are right—there's no undefined behavior here. Rather, the behavior is well defined: _return 3 if x≥0 and return an undefined value otherwise_. So the behavior isn't undefined, just the return value.

Comment: 3 is acceptable because the caller is not permitted to inspect the return value in that case. If it does, UB is invoked so any behavior is permissible.

Comment: @R. - Is there somewhere in the C language or llvm spec that says that? Frankly, I'm confused about why the compiler doesn't just reject this code outright, but if there's something along the lines of what you're saying in a spec somewhere then that would explain it.

Comment: @DaoWen *(C99, 6.9.1p12) "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @DaoWen: In regards to how reading an int could fail: on an architecture like the Itanic with hardware trapping for registers marked as containing junk, the compiler could choose to set the trap flag for the return value register when the function returns without a value.

Comment: I am accepting this answer based on the analysis of the C language semantics.  While this bothers me about C, the answer seems to be absolutely correct.